# How do I make this javascript execute its action only one time?

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a small javascript I am using to redirect viewers with screen resolutions less 
than X to my client's mobile landing page. On that mobile landing page is a link to
the normal homepage of the site - which also contains the redirect script.

So how do I only get the script to execute once so that when the mobile user goes to
the site they get redirected to the landing page, but if they click on the 'enter the
full site' link, they can do so without being redirected to the landing page again?

Here is the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 700) {
window.location = "http://scientific-practices.com/templates/anovascienceeducationmobile/home.html";
}
//-->
</script>
```

I don't need any settings being saved as cookies (I don't think), just simply 'the first
time the mobile user lands on the homepage during this visit, load the landing page. After that, let them see the regular homepage'.

Does that make sense?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You will need cookies, unless you want to pass a parameter specifying to not redirect in the query string.

Comment: Session Cookies....Server side session that adds code when needed.

Comment: use a url parameter/session value to check whether the user requested to view desktop site.

Comment: I thought you had to do `window.location.href`. Does simply `window.location` work?

Comment: window.location appears to work for me for the overall redirect

Comment: @crush Read the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: @epascarello Interesting that assigning a string to window.location doesn't overwrite the Location object with the string. Instead, it seems to invoke `window.location.assign()`

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are probably the way to go in most cases, but if you really need a JS-only solution you could use localStorage. Something like:

**Mobile:**

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('desiredState') === 'desktop' ) {
  window.location = 'http://www.site.com';
}

$('a#goto-desktop-site').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  localStorage.setItem('desiredState', 'desktop');
  window.location = 'http://www.site.com';
})
```

**Desktop:**

```
if ( localStorage.getItem('desiredState') === 'mobile' ) {
  window.location = 'http://m.site.com';
}

if ( !localStorage.getItem('desiredState') ) {
  if (screen.width <= 700) {
    window.location = 'http://m.site.com';
  }
}

$('a#goto-mobile-site').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  localStorage.setItem('desiredState', 'mobile');
  window.location = 'http://m.site.com';
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that in PHP:

### PHP

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['landing_page']))
    {
        $_SESSION['landing_page'] = "done";
        header('Location:http://scientific-practices.com/templates/anovascienceeducationmobile/home.html');
    }
    
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Employ the use of server side scripts to detect the device type then take the appropriate action....either redirect to `www.site.com/desktop` or `/mobile`
Try the following php snippet.

```
<?php
$m = preg_match('/android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],0,4));
//echo $m?"mobile":"desktop";
?>
```

if  `$m == TRUE`  you have yourself a mobile visitor.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I wanted to use server side originally but could not figure out how to exclude tablets from the string. I want tablets to go to the desktop version.

Comment: If layout is the problem then there may be a more elegant way using pure CSS! e.g. css rules for 640p tablet, landscape oriented:- 
`@media screen and (max-width: 640px) and (orientation: landscape){ body{ background:#000; } }`
That way, you don't have to maintain 2 different codebases that communicate the same message.